# Append to Azure Append Blob Using AppendTextAsync Results in Missing Data

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to create a logger for an application in Azure using the new Azure append blobs and the Azure Storage SDK 6.0.0.  So I created a quick test application to get a better understanding of append blobs and their performance characteristics.

My test program simply loops 100 times and appends a line of text to the append blob.  If I use the synchronous `AppendText()` method everything works fine, however, it appears to be limited to writing about 5-6 appends per second.  So I attempted to use the asynchronous `AppendTextAsync()` method; however, when I use this method, the loop runs much faster (as expected) but the append blob is missing about 98% of the appended text without any exception being thrown.

If I add a `Thread.Sleep` and sleep for 100 milliseconds between each append operation, I end up with about 50% of the data.  Sleep for 1 second and I get all of the data.

This seems similar to an issue that was discovered in v5.0.0 but was fixed in v5.0.2: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/releases/tag/v5.0.2

Here is my test code if you'd like to try to reproduce this issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var accountName = "<account-name>";

    var accountKey = "<account-key>;

    var credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);

    var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

    var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var container = client.GetContainerReference("<container-name>");

    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    var blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference("append-blob.txt");

    blob.CreateOrReplace();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        blob.AppendTextAsync(string.Format("Appending log number {0} to an append blob.\r\n", i));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong with my attempt to append lines of text to an append blob?  Otherwise, any idea why this would just lose data without throwing some kind of exception?

I'd really like to start using this as a repository for my application logs (since it was largely created for that purpose). However, it would be quite unreliable if logs would just go missing without warning if the rate of logging went above 5-6 logs per second.

Any thoughts or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I now have a working solution based upon the information provided by @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft.  According to the the API documentation, the `AppendTextAsync()` method should only be used in a single-writer scenario because the API internally uses the append-offset conditional header to avoid duplicate blocks which does not work in a multiple-writer scenario.

Here is the documentation that specifies this behavior is by design:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt423049.aspx

So the solution is to use the `AppendBlockAsync()` method instead.  The following implementation appears to work correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var message = string.Format("Appending log number {0} to an append blob.\r\n", i);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    tasks[i] = blob.AppendBlockAsync(stream);              
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

*Please note that I am not explicitly disposing the memory stream in this example as that solution would entail a using block with an async/await inside the using block in order to wait for the async append operation to finish before disposing the memory stream... but that causes a completely unrelated issue.*

Comment: This is a bug in Azure Storage Client Library 5.0.0, which is fixed in 5.0.2: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/09/02/issue-in-azure-storage-client-library-5-0-0-and-5-0-1-preview-in-appendblob-functionality.aspx , please update to the latest version.

Comment: @Zhaoxing I appreciate the suggestion to upgrade to 6.0.0; however, as I mentioned in the first paragraph of my post, I'm already using version 6.0.0.  In addition, I also explained in my first post that I already researched the bug that existed in 5.0.0 which was fixed in 5.0.2.  So unless the same bug was re-introduced in 6.0.0 this appears to be caused by something else.  Feel free to reproduce the issue using my code above using version 6.0.0 to confirm if you would like.  In the meantime, I might try to downgrade to version 5.0.2 to see if the issue exists in the previous version.

Comment: The documentation header of CloudAppendBlob.AppendTextAsync() mentioned: "This API should be used strictly in a single writer scenario
because the API internally uses the append-offset conditional header to avoid duplicate blocks which does not work in a multiple writer scenario." I guess the issue you encountered is by design.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, that's the missing piece of information that I've been looking for.  That explains why this hasn't been working as I expected.  In addition, it also confirms that the behavior is not a bug, but is, in fact, by design.  I'll update the solution to include you're new information, give you points for your post and comments, credit you in the solution, and mark the solution as the accepted answer.  I'll also update the issue I logged with the Azure Storage SDK project on GitHub. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `async` method incorrectly. `blob.AppendTextAsync()` is non-blocking, but it doesn't really finish when it returns. You should wait for all the `async` tasks before exiting from the process.

Following code is the correct usage:

```
var tasks = new Task[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    tasks[i] = blob.AppendTextAsync(string.Format("Appending log number {0} to an append blob.\r\n", i));

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I tried your solution as specified; unfortunately, it throws an Aggregate Exception with an inner exception message of: _"The remote server returned an error: (412) The append position condition specified was not met."_  I agree with you that I need to wait for the async tasks to complete, but I think there is something else wrong with either the `AppendTextAsync()` method or the way I'm using it.